# Magento 2 create new customer section

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

I want to create new customer section example **sampleorder**

url like : customer/account/sampleorders/

I tried below method that is working but it is the wrong way to modify core Magento files, what I tried is below, but I want to do it via module

1: create a file **Sampleorders.php**

vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/Sampleorders.php

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Customer\Controller\Account;

class Sampleorders extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
{

   /**
  * Index Action*
  * @return void
  */
  public function execute()
  {
       echo "hellow";
      exit();

  }
}
```

Comment: i have post here so please check and update me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Controller/Account**

**Sampleorders.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Sampleorders extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Default customer account page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "hellow";
        exit();
        //return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**customer_account_sampleorders.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Sample Orders</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">

        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">    
        <route id="customer">
            <module name="VendoreName_ModuleName" after="Magento_Customer"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Now run Magento command

```
php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d -f

php bin/magento c:c

php bin/magento c:f
```

and Clear your browser cache

> **url like : customer/account/sampleorders**

***I Hope This Helps You.***